# Stack arduino, motor shield and lcd shield

Tags: motor, lcd

I made arduino-stack which consists of arduino r3, robotdf motor shild and robotdf lcd shield. But motor shield and lcd use same pins 4 and 5, so we have a conflict of pins. Can i use other pins?

Comment: Nope. Welcome to shields.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it would be possible if you modify the shield right? cutting through a wire, solder it to another pin?

Comment: Technically you *can* rewire the shield. But this is a physical change, and different combinations of shields will require different rewiring. In the end you may be better off just using breakout boards instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this variant is ok for me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack one shield on top of the Arduino itself and connect the other shield using wires. This way you can pick your own pin assignment for the 'external' shield.

Be careful when using a specific library though, sometimes the used pins are hard-coded in the library itself. Modifying the .h and .cpp files for the library is possible, so you could (hard code) assign your own used pins.